# create android app using json parser and list view with intent do not work as it should

Tags: android, json, android-intent, android-listview

i ma creating android application that get data from web using json and put the data in a listview  then after the user click and select a specific data  the system will display details  in second activity that show the name and some details each value in a textview .

the problem is that after the user select from the list view the data displayed as a one block [image]

can anyone help me  to fix this error ??

## this is the onListItemClick

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {

            String item = (String)l.getItemAtPosition(position);


            //PostalCodes.get(position);
            /*
            String  PLACENAME = postalCode.get(PLACE_NAME_TAG).toString();
            String  LATITUDE = postalCode.get(LATITUDE_TAG).toString();
            String  LONGITUDE = postalCode.get(LONGITUDE_TAG).toString();
            String  POSTALCODE = postalCode.get(POSTAL_CODE_TAG).toString();
            */


            Log.e("position of the Item in the list", "you select the item number " + PostalCodes.getString(position));
            Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Row_Item.class);
            in.putExtra("placename", item);
        //  in.putExtra("lat",  LATITUDE);
        //  in.putExtra("lng", LONGITUDE);
        //  in.putExtra("postaCode", POSTALCODE);
            startActivity(in);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Error in the onListItemClick",
                    "LOOK AT THE onListItemClick method");
        }

    }
```

## the second activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_row__item);

        Place_Name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtlat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLAT);
        txtlng = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLNG);
        txtPostalCode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPSTC);


        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        value1 = b.getString("placename");
    //  value2 = b.getString("lat");
    //  value3 = b.getString("lng");
    //  value4 = b.getString("postaCode");

        Place_Name.setText(value1);
    //  txtlat.setText(value2);
    //  txtlng.setText(value3);
    //  txtPostalCode.setText(value4);



    }
```

## activity_row_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Row_Item" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="LAT" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="LNG" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="POSTAL CODE" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLAT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLNG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPSTC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: @ Shink what i want is that each value be putted in the right place as the value of lat must be in the textview of the LAT  and not be displayed the hall data like a one chunk

Comment: post your xml of second activity

Answer (score 0):

I would save the data in different TextViews. That seems to be the best way to get your data correctly.